# "Tex works editor and previewer has stopped working."

Tags: pdftex, compiling, windows

I have downloaded TexWorks and MikteX. I already had a file in Tex format which I wanted to open. So every time I open and try to compile it using the Green (PdfLatex) button it says "Tex works editor and previewer has stopped working." After this the program shuts down. 
I tried uninstalling every thing and re-installing it . But it just doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and the only way that I could solve is to delete the myfile.synctex.gz file along with all auxiliary files and also the output .pdf file.